# onchange event for input type="number"

Tags: jquery, html

How can I handle an onchange for `<input type="number" id="n" value="5" step=".5" />` ? I can't do a `keyup` or `keydown`, because, the user may just use the arrows to change the value.  I would want to handle it whenever it changes, not just on blur, which I think the `.change()` event does.  Any ideas?

Comment: You realize that input type is not supported by IE or Firefox?

Comment: Now it's supported by Firefox

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number

Yes, I am commenting on a question from six years ago.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Use mouseup and keyup

```
$(":input").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    alert("changed");            
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XezmB/2/

Comment: This will alert even if the value hasn't changed (just click anywhere in the `input`).

Comment: Yes it will. If that's a problem, you should keep track of the value in the input in a global variable or in a data element on the input. When the mouseup event calls your function, compare that value to the current value of the input. Only do something if the value has changed.

Comment: This doesn't work if value is changed by mouse scroll above the element.

Comment: Functionally it's not acting as change event.

Comment: Add the "mousewheel" event to support changes by scrolling.

Comment: If the user holds an arrow key down to change the value, then this doesn't fire until the arrow key is released. Using `input` instead (as suggested in another answer) seems to work better.

Answer (score 96):

The `oninput` event (`.bind('input', fn)`) covers any changes from keystrokes to arrow clicks and keyboard/mouse paste, but is not supported in IE <9.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#mirror').text($('#alice').val());

  $('#alice').on('input', function() {
    $('#mirror').text($('#alice').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="alice" type="number" step="any" value="99">

<p id="mirror"></p>
```

Answer (score 12):

http://jsfiddle.net/XezmB/8/

```
$(":input").bind('keyup change click', function (e) {
    if (! $(this).data("previousValue") || 
           $(this).data("previousValue") != $(this).val()
       )
   {
        console.log("changed");           
        $(this).data("previousValue", $(this).val());
   }

});


$(":input").each(function () {
    $(this).data("previousValue", $(this).val());
});​
```

This is a little bit ghetto, but this way you can use the "click" event to capture the event that runs when you use the mouse to increment/decrement via the little arrows on the input.  You can see how I've built in a little manual "change check" routine that makes sure your logic won't fire unless the value actually changed (to prevent false positives from simple clicks on the field).

Comment: Is this the real correct answer. The one currently marked correct with 168 upvotes triggers an event if the user clicks anywhere in the input box, rather than when the number is changed by clicking the arrow. Stack overflow has really gone downhill...

Answer (score 8):

To detect when mouse or key are pressed, you can also write:

```
$(document).on('keyup mouseup', '#your-id', function() {                                                                                                                     
  console.log('changed');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `$("input[type='number']")` doesn't work on IE, we should use a class name or id, for example, `$('.input_quantity')`.

And don't use `.bind()` method. The `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

So, my version is:

*HTML*

```
<input type="number" value="5" step=".5" min="1" max="999" id="txt_quantity" name="txt_quantity" class="input_quantity">
```

*jQuery*

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.input_quantity').on('change keyup', function() {
        console.log('nice');
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(':input').bind('click keyup', function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X8cV3/

Comment: This will still be executed if the value hasn't changed (just click anywhere in the `input`).

Comment: This is true, but once he captures the event he can determine if the value has changed or not.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input[type='number']").bind("focus", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).bind("blur", function() {
        if(value != $(this).val()) {
            alert("Value changed");
        }
        $(this).unbind("blur");
    });
});
```

OR

```
$("input[type='number']").bind("input", function() {
    alert("Value changed");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write a function in plain javascript and call it in the HTML code:

```
<input type="number" onchange="onChangeFunction(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better solution, but this is what came to mind:

```
var value = $("#yourInput").val();
$("#yourInput").on('keyup change click', function () {
    if(this.value !== value) {
        value = this.value;
        //Do stuff
    }        
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/XezmB/7/).

It simply binds an event handler to the `keyup`, `change` and `click` events. It checks whether or not the value has changed, and if so, stores the current value so it can check again next time. The check is required to deal with the `click` event.

Comment: Cluttering the global scope with a variable named `value` is asking for trouble.

Comment: Very true. Like your answer though, it's just an example. I think @JakeFeasel probably has the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" id="n" value="0" step=".5" />
<input type="hidden" id="v" value = "0"/>

<script>
$("#n").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    var current = $("#n").val();
    var prevData = $("#v").val(); 
    if(current > prevData || current < prevData){
       $("#v").val(current);
       var newv = $("#v").val(); 
       alert(newv);
    } 
});  
</script>
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/patrickrobles53/s10wLjL3/
>
> I've used a hidden input type to be the container of the previous
>   value that will be needed for the comparison on the next change.

Comment: you can use just `data-prev` attribute to store previous value. No need to use extra input

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I solved using this code

HTML

```
<span id="current"></span><br>
<input type="number" id="n" value="5" step=".5" />
```

You can add just 3 first lines the others parts is optional.

```
$('#n').on('change paste', function () {
    $("#current").html($(this).val())   
});
// here when click on spinner to change value, call trigger change
$(".input-group-btn-vertical").click(function () {
   $("#n").trigger("change");
});
// you can use this to block characters non numeric
$("#n").keydown(function (e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 || (e.keyCode === 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) 
           return;

    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) 
       e.preventDefault();
});
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/XezmB/1303/