# jQuery event when a type number field is modified by the arrows aside of the field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this input type="number" field on my application:

```
<input type="number" id="quantidade" class="form-control">
```

So I have this jQuery code to execute some stuff at the event keyup:

```
$("#quantidade").keyup(function(event){
    //code that's working like a charm
});
```

That's working well when the user enter some value on the field. But, in browsers like Chrome and Firefox, type number fields have two little arrows aside the field to increase or decrease the value:

[image]

Clicking on these arrows does not active the keyup event. So, how can I activate the same code when the user click on the arrows? Which kind of event I can use for that?

Comment: have you tried on change event ?

Comment: Yes, I tried the change event, but this did not work. Now it's working well. I don't know what happened.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try that one :

```
$("#quantidade").on("keyup keydown change",function(event){
    //code that's working like a charm
});
```

Comment: That works! Thank you. I really don't know why, but I tried to use the change event and did not work. Now works great.

Comment: Glat it worked, Accept it as your answer if it worked :)

Comment: I'll do this. I have just to wait some minutes.

Comment: Not working properly if I press the up/down arrows for a few seconds. These events worked for me: "keyup change click". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609731/onchange-event-for-input-type-number