# What JQuery event fires when you change the value (and hold) of an input type number?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find the JQuery event that fires when you hold the up or down buttons on an input of type number. The `change` event fires once you release the button, but it does not fire progressively as you hold it. What event should I use if I want it to fire every time the number changes in the input?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609731/onchange-event-for-input-type-number 2nd answer.  it seems that .on('input') does what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `'input'` Event

```js
$('[type="number"]').on('input', function(e) {
  console.log(e.type)
})
```

```html
Use keyboard arrows or Input's UI arrows:<br>
<input type="number" name="">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`'keypress'` Event works only on type=text

```js
$('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log(e.type)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" value="text type">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```